# Lua: Tables: compare keys (not their values)

Tags: lua

I'm very new to lua, so please don't mind the novice question. I wasn't able to find my exact question here because of the weird wording.

I have the following table:

```
local DialogueMode = {
  uniqueDialogue = {0, 3},
  general = {1, 2},
  job = {3, 5},
  rumors = {4, 3},
  annoyed = {5, 0},
  pissed = {6, 0},
  ignore = {7, 0}
}
```

And the following loop:

```
  for k,v in pairs(DialogueMode) do
    print(k .. ' ' .. tostring(isDialogueModeCompatible(playerTools, npc, k)))
  end
```

And here's the if function:

```
local function isDialogueModeCompatible(playerTools, npc, dialogueMode)
  print(tostring(dialogueMode) .. " " .. tostring(DialogueMode.uniqueDialogue) .. " " .. tostring(dialogueMode == DialogueMode.uniqueDialogue))
end
```

For uniqueDialogue, it prints out:

```
uniqueDialogue table: 4df7e3ad false
```

Why isn't dialogueMode == DialogueMode.uniqueDialogue working as I expect it should, and how do I make it work how I expect it? Where I'm checking if the dialogueMode is equal to the key in the table. I'm effectively trying to use the table as an enumerator, but this is giving me problems.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently v stores the correct comparison.

I.E.

```
  for mode, value in pairs(DialogueMode) do
      print(tostring(value) .. " " .. tostring(DialogueMode.uniqueDialogue) .. " ")
  end
```

Prints:

```
table: 140b90e8 table: 140b90e8
```

Answer (score 1):

The question here is, what are you trying to print? Do you want it to just dump the table? If you want the function to recursively search through the table and print it out, that's more complicated than what you've got here, simply because of the nature of recursion.

Additionally, the reason `dialogueMode == Dialoguemode.uniqueDialog` is returning false is because `dialogueMode` was assigned the value `k`, which is the string `"uniqueDialog"`. 
 `Dialoguemode.uniqueDialog` is the entire `uniqueDialog` table, whereas `dialogueMode` is just the key, the name of the table, converted to a string.

The code could look like:

```
--Not my code, credit here: https://gist.github.com/hashmal/874792
function tprint(tbl, indent)
  if not indent then indent = 0 end
  for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
    formatting = string.rep("  ", indent) .. k .. ": "
    if type(v) == "table" then
      print(formatting)
      tprint(v, indent+1)
    else
      print(formatting .. v)
    end
  end
end

tprint(DialogueMode)
```

Note that this might not work for all cases but for your table it does dump the entire table successfully. If you run into errors, check that github for a fix (or fix it yourself :D)

Here's the output I get when using your DialogueMode table:

```
pissed:     
  1: 6  
  2: 0  
rumors:     
  1: 4  
  2: 3  
general:    
  1: 1  
  2: 2  
ignore:     
  1: 7  
  2: 0  
annoyed:    
  1: 5  
  2: 0  
job:    
  1: 3  
  2: 5  
uniqueDialogue:     
  1: 0  
  2: 3
```

EDIT: Not sure what you're looking for exactly, this might not be it but hopefully it's helpful to you in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Again I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, but maybe you can modify this code and work from there. This code loops through and checks to see if it can find an identical table within DialogueMode to the one it's currently printing. If the table isn't the same it won't print "true" next to the table.

Anyways, here's the code, I hope it'll be helpful to you in some way. Feel free to delete this answer if it isn't:

```
local DialogueMode = {
  uniqueDialogue = {0, 3},
  general = {1, 2},
  job = {3, 5},
  rumors = {4, 3},
  annoyed = {5, 0},
  pissed = {6, 0},
  ignore = {7, 0}
}

local function isDialogueModeCompatible(playerTools, npc, dialogueMode)
  for v, x in pairs(DialogueMode) do
    if (DialogueMode[v] == dialogueMode) then
      bool = true;
      int = v;
      break;
    end
  end
  return(tostring(dialogueMode)..". Match Found: "..tostring(bool));
end

for k,v in pairs(DialogueMode) do
  print(k .. ' ' .. tostring(isDialogueModeCompatible(playerTools, npc, v)));
end
```